# Rolling Total in Access based on license start and end

Tags: ms-access, graph

I am trying to create a rolling total against this base data in order to use as a line graph in Access.

The Base data has start and end dates for licenses, so basically when a license starts the running total is incremented and when it expires the total is removed.

```
Start Monday    End Monday  Product SumOfHCPOQty
26-Aug-19   10-Feb-20   Houdini Core Local Access License   4.00
02-Dec-19   16-Dec-19   Houdini Core Local Access License   4.00
02-Sep-19   10-Feb-20   Houdini Core Local Access License   1.00
02-Dec-19   24-Feb-20   Houdini Core Local Access License   11.00
02-Dec-19   13-Apr-20   Houdini Core Local Access License   2.00
02-Dec-19   15-Jun-20   Houdini Core Local Access License   4.00
02-Dec-19   05-Jan-37   Houdini Core Local Access License   6.00
```

I have this working in Excel, but I want it in Access to display with some other report information.

So in Excel I have an addition and expiries column which is used as the sum for the total and then the total is added to the previous rows total.

In Excel, I have this output based on the above base data

```
License                            Start Monday Addit   Expire  Total
Houdini Core Local Access License   12-Aug-19   0.00    0.00    0.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   19-Aug-19   0.00    0.00    0.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   26-Aug-19   4.00    0.00    4.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   02-Sep-19   1.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   09-Sep-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   16-Sep-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   23-Sep-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   30-Sep-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   07-Oct-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   14-Oct-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   21-Oct-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   28-Oct-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   04-Nov-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   11-Nov-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   18-Nov-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   25-Nov-19   0.00    0.00    5.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   02-Dec-19   27.00   0.00    32.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   09-Dec-19   0.00    0.00    32.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   16-Dec-19   0.00    -4.00   28.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   23-Dec-19   0.00    0.00    28.00
Houdini Core Local Access License   30-Dec-19   0.00    0.00    28.00
```

I have tried some DSUM calculations and the like and have a basic rolling total but it is a complete mess as I need to be able to plot it against a years worth of Mondays as seen in the output data (it's a subset but you can see how the date is padded out).

Would love to hear some suggestions on this as I am a bit lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up "running total".

Comment: Cross post https://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2057963&hl=